# What ordering is used in Access 2010 XML export?

Tags: microsoft-access, export

What ordering is used by Access 2010 when the `Export > XML File` dialog is used?

I'm trying to discern the sorting but I can't see it, even though the export file is the same every time. Furthermore the `Apply Sorting` checkbox is disabled, so I can't choose a sorting method.

Answer (score 1):

It will export in the same order that the table is in.  If you would like to control the ordering then your best bet is to create a query that sorts everything as you see fit.  After that you can export your query to XML and the sorting in that query will be visible.